# query if page has not child

Tags: query, child-pages

I'm trying to create a page which display a few of sub pages (child pages), however if the page has not child I would like to display a message.

I cannot get a query that allow me to do something like this:

```
 if (Page has childs) {
    do this
 }
 else {
    display this
 }
```

Any help?

Thanks in advanced

Comment: I accept em all the time, I haven't had the time to check this specific since I didn't spect to get the answer so fast and is friday night so basically will be a few hours  until I get in my computer again, also I saw u gave me an answer, I'd appreciated your time, and will be happy to give you the points later, Regards

Comment: Oh that's alright, was just a friendly reminder. Just trying to do the best I can to contribute here! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_parent' => $post_id
);
$children = get_posts( $args );

if( count( $children ) > 0 ) {
    //has children
} else {
    //does not have children
}
```

Docs: [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)

This should also allow you to have access to the data of the children, should you need it. If you need any additional parameters in `$args` (a post type, for example), make sure to include those.

Answer (score 1):

What about using something like this (provided you have a way to get the ID of the page you are checking for child pages):

`$children = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID ) );`

However if you want to get just direct descendants, see m0r7if3r's, or this would also work too:

`$children = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID, 'parent' => 0 ) );`

And then check that using `count($children)` with an if statement like so:

```
if( count( $children ) > 0 ) {
    // has children (and grandchildren if not using the 'parent' param)
} else {
    // does not have children
}
```

Comment: Could use a few more args, but I like the way you think ;)

Comment: Yeah definitely lol, this will also grab the grandchildren of the page if any, `'parent' => 0` would be more suitable if he's just looking for direct descendants along with the `child_of` parameter.